# Make Associative array with three element in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want three element in associative array, so far am successful in getting two in the array.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `notification_table` ";
$resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsd1);

$associativeArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsd1))
{
 $associativeArray[$row['name']] = $row['price'] ;  
 }
 foreach($associativeArray as $k => $id){
 echo $k."=>".$id .' ';
}
```

And am getting the response like this

```
name1=>24.725 name2=>24.265
```

Now i want to add another column in array as well and the name is column is ***notification_check*** . 
Am not able to get how to add three columns in a single array. Any help will be appreciated.

I want the output like `name1=>24.725=>yes_notification  name2=>25.43=>no_notification`

And when i print_r($row) is show this output `Array ( [sno] => 1 [name] => name1  [price] => 23 [notification_check] => yes_notification)`

Comment: `$associativeArray['notification_check'] = 'some value';`?

Comment: I want name , price and notification check all three in the associative array

Comment: Can you show us what output you're trying to achieve? Arrays don't really have "columns", so I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: You are already doing it using `$associativeArray[$row['name']] = $row['price'] ;` and that's how you add key values. Did you copy that code from somewhere?

Comment: Notification_table has 3 columns i.e. name, price and notification_check. I want values from all three column in array. But so far am only able to get the value of two columns. How to add third element in array

Comment: Try `print_r($row)` to debug

Comment: It prints all three column when i use print_r($row)

Comment: You still didn't tell us what output you want.

Comment: Post the contents of `$row`

Comment: There might be a conflict with `$row['name']`

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: Oh! No no vidhi, you can't do this. You need to create an array instead of `$row['price']`, try `$associativeArray[$row['name']] = array($row['price'], $row['notification_check']);`

Comment: And your foreach will be `foreach($associativeArray as $k => $id){
 echo "$k=>" . $id[0] . " :: " . $id[1];`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten this and use `mysqli_fetch_all` to create an array of all of the data and then manipulate the array using `array_column` to create the index...

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($resultsd1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$associativeArray = array_column($result, null, 'name');
```